# Targeting Priorities in StarCraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do units choose which enemy to target in SC2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/how-do-units-choose-which-enemy-to-target-in-sc2)

Somewhere I read about targeting priority.  For instance, if you focus fire on a Probe, and after it dies you army will continue to kill Probes, but when suddenly Zealots show up, the units will automatically start targeting the Zealots because it has a higher targeting priority?  Is this true?  If so what about when dealing with other unit types?  Is there some table with the targeting priorities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple targeting priority for units is that they will attack something that is attacking them if there is nothing attacking them they will attack the first unit they encounter, then buildings.

IE. You attack a probe with a marine, a zealot starts attacking the marine, after the probe dies, the marine will attack a zealot.

Comment: There should be a specific command for attacking probes only!